# Mongoose queries with async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, async-await

I have an application where logged in users can create new users and add them to one of their groups.  You can see the middleware flow for this in the route:

```
router.post('/account/add-users',
  userController.validateRegister,
  userController.registerUser,
  userController.getNewUser,
  groupController.addUserToGroup
);
```

I am using Passport for registration / authentication.

Essentially once I have registered the new user I would like to be able to add them to the group the the creator has specified.

My validateRegister method looks like:

```
exports.validateRegister = (req, res, next) => {
 req.sanitizeBody('name');
 req.checkBody('name', 'You must supply a name!').notEmpty();
 if(req.body.email){
  req.checkBody('email', 'That Email is not valid!').isEmail();
  req.sanitizeBody('email').normalizeEmail({
   gmail_remove_dots: false,
   remove_extension: false,
   gmail_remove_subaddress: false
  });
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password Cannot be Blank!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password-confirm', 'Confirmed Password cannot be blank!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password-confirm', 'Oops! Your passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);  
  };
  const errors = req.validationErrors();
 if (errors) {
    req.flash('error', errors.map(err => err.msg));
    res.render('login', { title: 'Register', body: req.body, flashes: 
    req.flash() });
    return; // stop the fn from running
  }
  next(); // there were no errors!
};
```

registerUser is:

```
exports.registerUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('registering user');
  if(req.body.email){
    await User.register(new User({email: req.body.email, name: 
    req.body.name, userType: req.body.userType}), 
    req.body.password, 
    function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('error while user register!', err);
        return next(err);
      }
      console.log('user registered!');                      
      res.redirect('/');
     }
   );
} else {
  console.log('NO EMAIL PROVIDED');
  await User.register(new User({name: req.body.name, userType: 
  req.body.userType}), 
  req.body.password, 
  function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('error while user register!', err);

        return next(err);
      }        
    });
 };
 console.log(' user registered!');

// the below are values from the form that I will need to add users to a group
 res.locals.chosenGroup = req.body.group; 
 res.locals.newUserUserName = req.body.name;
 res.locals.newUserUserType = req.body.userType;
 next();
 };
```

getNewUser is below and this is where things break down. The console.log will correctly print the value of `res.locals.newUserUserName` but when I try to use that value in the `User.find` nothing comes back

```
exports.getNewUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('IN GETNEWUSER '+res.locals.newUserUserName);
  res.locals.newUser = await User.find( { "name" : 
  res.locals.newUserUserName } );
  if (!res.locals.newUser) {
    console.log('User is not available yet!');
  } else {
    console.log('USER IN REGSITER USER FUNCTION IN GETNEWUSER METHOD 
    '+res.locals.newUser);
  }
 next();
};
```

I assume this is because the user is not yet in the DB (if i hard code the name of the user into the query and go through the process again the correct record is returned which suggests it's a timing issue) so I guess I'm doing something wrong with my async / awaits.  However the `console.log(' user registered!')` in `registerUser` shows in terminal before any of the logs in `getNewUser` so I'm a bit stumped!

----Edit----

OK, so if in registerUser I use Promisify to rewrite

```
User.register(new User({name: req.body.name, userType: 
req.body.userType}), 
req.body.password, 

function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error while user register!', err);

    return next(err);
  }        
});
```

to

```
const user = new User({ name: req.body.name, userType: req.body.userType });
const register = promisify(User.register, User);
await register(user, req.body.password);
```

then everything works.  I'd really like to understand why though.

Comment: Where does the User.register come from? That's not a mongoose function. Also you don't use callback functions with async/await, that's the whole point of async/await...to avoid using callbacks

Comment: thanks @EndaMolloy register is from Passport.js.  Good spot with the awaits on the callback functions - I've removed but it doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

In your registerUser function, it seems user.Register() uses a callback so it does not need to be "awaited", did you try removing the async/await from those two lines and testing it again?

Comment: Thanks.  I've remove d the awaits on User.register(new User... but it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are calling the next middleware before the User.Register callback, that's the reason for it not being created on the next middleware.

Can you try the following snippet:

```
exports.registerUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('registering user');
  if (req.body.email) {
    await User.register(new User({
        email: req.body.email, 
        name: req.body.name, 
        userType: req.body.userType
      }),
      req.body.password,
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('error while user register!', err);
          return next(err);
        }
        console.log('user registered!');

        // this calls the userController.getNewUser only after the user registers
        // I'm not sure you need set the res.locals variables here as well
        next();
      }
    );
  } else {
    console.log('NO EMAIL PROVIDED');
    await User.register(new User({
        name: req.body.name, 
        userType: req.body.userType
      }),
      req.body.password,
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('error while user register!', err);
          return next(err);
        }
        console.log(' user registered!');

        // the below are values from the form that I will need to add users to a group
        res.locals.chosenGroup = req.body.group;
        res.locals.newUserUserName = req.body.name;
        res.locals.newUserUserType = req.body.userType;
        next();
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have to pop out for a bit but please see my edit at the bottom of my question. I can rewrite using promisify and it will work